# How to dynamically createelement with ngif in it

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, createelement, angularjs-ng-class

I'm adding elements to the document and I'd like to add this one
`<button *ngIf="isPlaying()" (click)="backward15Sec()" class="control-btn backward-btn" [ngClass]="{'disabled':!isBackwardBtnEnabled()}"></button>`

```
const btnElem = document.createElement("button");       
btnElem.className = "control-btn backward-btn";
btnElem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    this.backward15Sec();//your typescript function
});
document.getElementById("userDetails").appendChild(btnElem);
```

1. How can I add the `*ngIf=` and `[ngClass]=` programmatically?
2. Why when setting the class name programmatically the css style of the class name is not taking?

Comment: Why are you creating elements like that at all? Can you explain that, because there might be an Angular approach.

Comment: @Silvermind it's part of a product requirement, we are getting information by push from multiple sources and when they arrive we analyze, process and manipulate the data as well as decide which elements to display in the dashboard. There is no html or template we can use we have to built it each time the data arrives

Comment: @Silvermind you're missing the point. The question is not about any specific element or a specific case, it can be ANY element with ANY attribute &property !!!.
I need to dynamically programmatically attach/ bind properties & attributes that are not part of the element (don't have a setter) like ng* (ngif/ngfor/ngClass/ ...) and the style defined in css class apply to them(which currently doesn't). 
To conclude: its not about the image, the button or any of the elements its about the *ng and the style. If you truly wish to help, then trust that I know what I need & help with  code example.

Answer (score 0):

in the question code you are creating elements by yourself, without angular context or something simillar. you can't just apply directives to such elements. Instead you could track changes of you `ended` field and add/remove the element whenever you want

```
set ended(val) { 
  if(val) {
    this.reattachElement();
  } else {
    this.removeElement();
  }
}
elementToRender = ...; // your element will be here;
reattachElement() {
   document.getElementById("userDetails").appendChild(this.elementToRender);
}
removeElement() {
   this.elementToRender.remove();
}
```